# Assert Two Frames Are Not Equal

Tags: python, unit-testing, pandas

I need to test that two pandas dataframes are *not* equal.
Is there an equivalent to pandas `assert_frame_equal` function that does this? If not, what's the best/safest way to assert that the frames aren't equal?

Comment: Equal in what sense?  All cells are equal considering indices?  Or do they have to be sorted equivalently as well?

Comment: @piRSquared I believe this is asked in a unit testing context, e.g., `pandas.util.testing.assert_frame_equal`

Comment: Thanks @PaulH, That's exactly the context.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could write your own assertion function that uses `assert_frame_equal()` and inverts the result:

```
def assert_frame_not_equal(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        assert_frame_equal(*args, **kwargs)
    except AssertionError:
        # frames are not equal
        pass
    else:
        # frames are equal
        raise AssertionError
```

This will use the same logic that `assert_frame_equal()` uses for comparing data frames, so the question of what constitutes equality is avoided - inequality is simply the opposite of whatever `assert_frame_equal()` determines.

Comment: Yeah, that's the route I'm thinking of going down. I was just surprised that this hasn't been solved before.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is :

```
# Let us suppose you have two dataframes df1 and df2
# Check for equality by using
df1.equals(df2)
```

Use `not` to assert that they are not equal

Comment: not quite. this will return a dataframe of booleans, not a scalar value. thus the truthiness of `is_equal = df1.equals(df2)` means that `assert is_equal` will never raise

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) returns a ```bool```: True if all elements are the same in both objects, False otherwise. So this works (at least for ```pandas==0.25.3```).
It's [pandas.DataFrame.eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html#pandas.DataFrame.eq) that returns a dataframe of booleans.

Answer (score 1):

For one-off comparisons between 2 pandas dataframes I don't expect to be equal in a [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/unittest.html) unit test, I just do:

```
import pandas as pd

with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df2, df1)
```